# Why does this BufferImage render method work?

Tags: java, variables, graphics, game-engine

After trawling through the internet looking for graphics methods for a main game loop engine, I came across the code below, and have little clue as to how it works.

```
public class Game extends Canvas {

    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    private void tick() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            pixels[i] = i;
        }
    }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
}
```

There are two things I do not understand about this code:

1)    In the render method, you set g to bs.getDrawGraphics(), then use the graphics, and dispose of the graphics object. If you are not altering bs from this, rather setting g from bs, then shouldn't the image be destroyed with g?

2)   You set the image variable, then the pixels array from the image. If you do not directly alter the image variable, then how can you change the value of image through the pixels array without setting it after changing the pixels array?

Many thanks.

Comment: Graphics#dispose releases any native resources that the Graphics context might be holding onto, but doesn't effect anything actually painted to do. The pixels array has direct access to underlying image data, manipulating the array changes the underlying image directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You dispose the graphics context, any changes made before are not affected by this, since `Graphics` isn't the object that holds the actual pixel data.
2. The `pixels` array is a direct reference to the `BufferedImage`'s raster. They're the same thing, so there's no need to do any magic to "flush" the pixels back to the image.